# Asserting all different possibilities

Tags: prolog

I have this code which asserts fact based on lists of other facts, however I have difficulty doing 2 things:

First, I want it to assert all the different possible facts.

Second, I want it to be able to use lists of variable lengths. The code I have only works if the lists are exactly 2 and 4 of length, which works for testing but will not work in practice.

```
assert_test([Fact], [Z,Z2], [Y, Y2, Y3, Y4]) :-
    Z,
    Z2,
    Y,
    Y2,
    Y3,
    Y4,
    assertz(Fact).
```

I really have no clue as to what kind of solution I need for my problems, I would really appreciate any pointer that could help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very clear, but it seems like you want to (a) call a number of goals passed in as a list, then (b) assert all those goals. I will answer under the assumption that this is true, although this operation as written is almost certainly not useful.

To call some variable `V`, you can just put `V` as a goal in your rule body, as you did, or you can apply the `call/1` predicate to it, i.e., write `call(V)`. Thus, to call a list of goals, you can do `maplist(call, Goals)`.

Similarly, to assert a list of goals, you can do `maplist(assertz, Goals)`.

So overall, here is one way of doing what you might want:

```
test_assert(Goals) :-
    maplist(call, Goals),
    maplist(assertz, Goals).
```

This applies to a list `Goals` of any length.

If your Prolog doesn't have an implementation of `maplist/2` or you don't want to use it, you might instead write a recursive solution, something like:

```
test_assert([]).
test_assert([Goal|Goals]) :-
    call(Goal),
    assertz(Goal),
    test_assert(Goals).
```

(None of this is tested.) Note that this interleaves the call and assert operations, so they are performed in a different order than in the approach using `maplist/2`.